# user password expiring everyday in Linux

Tags: password

I have a user account for Oracle on a Redhat Enterprise Linux 6.8 server. It is supposed to have a non-expiring password, therefore I have disabled password ageing using

```
chage -I -1 -m 0 -M 99999 -E -1 oracle
```

I double check to make sure that password says never expire.
However the next day, I see that the password has expired and the cron jobs are failing.Output of `chage -l` is:

```
Last password change : password must be changed
Password expires : password must be changed
Password inactive : password must be changed
Account expires : never
Minimum number of days between password change : 0
Maximum number of days between password change : 90
Number of days of warning before password expires : 14
```

Also in `var/log/secure` I see this:

```
chage[16948]: changed password expiry for oracle
Password does meet requirements.
```

I would appreciate some help. Thanks

Comment: why didn't you use `-M -1` as hinted by man page ?

Comment: I believe that chage -M 99999 will allow maximum number of days between password change. I have used the same command on other servers and it seems to work for them.

Comment: Debian sets the max age to 99999 too by default. Seems like it should work. Can you check if the changes are made as expected in `/etc/shadow`, and if it gets changed when you check the next day? (Or where ever the user is stored. Don't post the password hash.)

Comment: Also try changing the password to see if that gets it out of some "zomg! the password expired!" state.

Answer (score -1):

that command should work. You should watch OR take a look at the /var/log/secure (or /var/log/auth.log on some distros). See if there are any failed attempts to login to oracle.

If your server is public facing, no doubt it is being hammered by a brute force attack.

check sshd and see if you have `MaxAuthTries` set; that would lock out the user if there are to many ssh attempts.

you might want to disable oracle ssh all together `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Match User oracle
    PasswordAuthentication no
```

Comment: What is the relevance of your `sshd` suggestions to password ageing?

Comment: `MaxAuthTries: Specifies the maximum number of authentication attempts permitted per connection.  Once the number of failures reaches half this value, additional failures are logged.  The default is 6.` -- I doubt `sshd` would lock user accounts by default after just six failed logins. Note that it says "per connection".